# Where can we buy chlorinated paraffin for lab application?

Tags: organic-chemistry

Any idea where to buy chlorinated paraffin for lab application? We need very viscous analog of $\ce{CHCl_3}$.

Should we think about synthesizing it?

I found a lot of places where I could buy 5 tons:) But we need only few liters for the rest of our life.

Comment: You ask any manufacturer/distributor if they will send you samples.

Comment: How about you tell your teacher to buy some for the whole class?

Comment: @Simon-Nail-It, that is nice. But we do not have teachers over here in the University. And basically my boss (teacher) asked me to buy clean one, but did not said where...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about chemistry.

Answer (score 1):

Sigma-Aldrich is a global supplier of purified chemicals for research users.

They have a whole page of the [haloalkane compounds](http://www.sigmaaldrich.com/chemistry/chemistry-products.html?TablePage=16272014) they sell (in small quantities such as you desire).  You might be interested in compounds such as trichloropropane, pentachloroethane, etc.

A reason it might be difficult to get the higher-molecular weight compounds is that they are toxic and difficult to dispose of properly.  In the US, their use is subject to [increasing regulatory requirements](http://www.doverchem.com/Portals/0/CP%20Regulatory%20Update%2006-13-13.pdf).